# Probability of different events in an uneven spinner

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have a spinner with 3 different sections of unequal probability for it to land on. Getting a 1 is 1/10, and a 2 is 1/5. What is the probability of getting both a 1 and a 2 in 10 spins?

I thought I could find the probability of getting at least one 1 and then multiply it by the probability of getting a 2 in the remaining tries.

That is $(1 - \frac{9}{10}^{10}) * (1-\frac{4}{5}^{9}) = 0.564$

However, if you do this the other way around you get $(1 - \frac{9}{10}^{9}) * (1-\frac{4}{5}^{10}) = 0.547$, which makes me fairly sure this is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! On this forum, you are expected to show what efforts you have put in and where you are stuck for appropriate help to be rendered. Please edit it in.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have done that now.

Comment: You can use inclusion/exclusion to find the probability that you don't get both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute **1** missing: $0.9^{10}$

Compute **2** missing: $0.8^{10}$

So is the answer $\quad1 - 0.9^{10} - 0.8^{10} \;?$

Not quite, you have counted **1** and **2** both missing twice, correct for that

Comment: So it would be $1−0.9^{10}−0.8^{10}+0.7^{10} = 0.572$

Comment: Yes,  I guessed that you have understood that this is the right way to apply inclusion-exclusion. Cheers !   I am confirming it for anyone else who might chance upon the question.